# How to drop columns in data frame based on their contribution to the sum over all columns in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to drop columns from my data frame based on their contribution to the sum across all columns.

An example with an 1x5 data frame would be the following (I suppose it would also be possible to drop rows from a 5x1 data frame in a similar way and then transpose it). Assume the values sum up to 100.

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = 5, V2 = 10, V3 = 20, V4 = 40, V5 = 25)

V1    V2     V3    V4    V5  

5     10     20    40    25
```

I now want to keep the columns that contribute the most to e.g. at least 80% of the sum over all columns.

So what I want to achieve is:

```
V3    V4    V5  

20    40    25
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(df, everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
    filter(!lag(cumsum(value) >  80, default = FALSE)) %>%
    deframe 
# V4 V5 V3 
#40 25 20
```

---

Or if we need in the same order

```
pivot_longer(df, everything()) %>%
      arrange(desc(value)) %>%
      filter(!lag(cumsum(value) >  80, default = FALSE)) %>% 
      arrange(match(name, names(df))) %>% 
      mutate(rn = 1) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
      select(-rn)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for since I have some data wrangling anyway using dplyr! :)

Answer (score 5):

There could be many possible approaches that can be taken. One way in base R would be to `unlist` the data, `sort` it in decreasing order and take cumulative sum of the ratio of values. Stop when it reaches the threshold (`0.8`) and select all the columns till that.

```
vals <- cumsum(prop.table(sort(unlist(df), decreasing = TRUE))) > 0.8
df[names(vals[1:which.max(vals)])]

#  V4 V5 V3
#1 40 25 20
```

Comment: I always love your short base R solutions :). However, note that you actually take 85%. As 80% crosses between the columns.

Comment: yes, but that is what I interpreted from OP's expected output and description `at least 80% of the sum`. So 80% and above.

Comment: Yes, it's AT LEAST 80% what I was looking for :) So 85% is fine, thanks for your answer and of course also thanks for all the other contributions!

Comment: My mistake, my apologies

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyvesre` approach, I created a row id, `gather`ed the data, sorted the values in `des`cending order, calculated the cumulative percent and `filter`ed columns below 0.8.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  gather(var, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
  mutate(sum = (cumsum(value) / sum(value))) %>% 
  filter(sum < 0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

A , B and C are examples of columns, which min identifies the column with the minimum value (thus, the one that "contributes less" to the sum)

```
A <- c(5)
B <- c(6)
C <-c(4)
df <- cbind(A, B , C)
# condition 1
cond <- which.min(df)
mask <- df[,-cond]
```

Comment: Rather than simply posting code, please add an explanation of what the code is doing and how it answers the question